# Room Effects in UE with Resonance Audio

Tags: resonance-audio

I'm working on a VR game at the moment in UE AND FMOD. We're trying to implement the Room Effects, as has been done so neatly with the Unity plugin.

We've successfully managed to create a room within a collider which seems to work with the room effects, however, we're having trouble having more than one room in the same map/level so we can change the room effect as we walk through the level.

has anyone managed to get room effects working in UE before, as in unity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At present, with the Resonance Audio FMOD plugin combined with UE, you can pass new 'RoomProperties' to the Listener plugin via a call to

```
setParameterData(int index, void *data, unsigned int length);
```

From C++.

You must, however, handle detection of movement between different "rooms" yourself.

As I believe you most likely already know, you should pass a pointer to an instance of the RoomProperties struct, found here: https://github.com/resonance-audio/resonance-audio-fmod-sdk/blob/master/Plugins/include/RoomProperties.h
cast to void pointer, with the `index` parameter set to 1 and the `length` parameter set to `sizeof(RoomProperties)`

Answer (score 1):

You can create multiple Room Effect 'zones' using Unreal's *Audio Volumes*.

Add a new *Audio Volume*, go to its *Details* panel and open the *Reverb* tab. You should see a *Reverb Plugin Effect* drop-down list. Locate the *Create New Asset* section and select **Resonance Audio Reverb Plugin Preset** to create a new reverb preset.

Then, in your new **Resonance Audio Reverb Plugin Presets** you can select some unique room effect settings for the volume you've just created.

You then repeat the process for additional 'rooms'.

You can also add a **Global Reverb Preset** if you would like to use some 'default' room effects settings (for example, when the player is no longer in any of the *Audio Volumes*).

Please see: https://developers.google.com/resonance-audio/develop/unreal/developer-guide#using_the_resonance_audio_reverb_plugin for more info!

Comment: I forgot to add.... Most importantly... That we're using fmod. I REALLY should have put this in the original post!

Answer (score 0):

i have been unable to get the audio volume resonance reverbs to work with stock UE4 (4.19.1, with resonance 1.0 that doesn't require a custom build).  i can get the master reverb to work, but not just for the audio volumes.  any advice on this?

this issue is also posted here:
https://forums.unrealengine.com/development-discussion/audio/1472284-reverb-plugin-of-google-resonance-for-ue4-doesn-t-work